# Eclipse: start new java project in one step?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a total newbie to programming and just started learning JAVA i order to program Android apps.

I started out with netbeans and got familiar with it quickly. I then changed to eclipse because of the Android support. But if I just want to make a simple java project in eclipse then the wizard doesn't ask for a package name and I have to add the package afterwards.

Isn't it possible to create a package from the wizard - just like in netbeans (and like when you create an android project in eclipse)?

Comment: You can create new packages when you create a [new class](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-wizard-class.htm) just by typing the name into the box. They don't have to exist beforehand. _I'm not sure why creating a package at project creation time would be useful; there isn't a 1-1 relationship between these two things._

Comment: @McDowell Think it might be because I'm only used to be working with one package - as mentioned I'm a newbie..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this. http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-9.htm

You can do it while creating a class i.e. specify the name of the package.

Comment: thanks that reduces it from 3 steps to 2. Was hoping to be able to do it in one go. But thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Click on File -> New Project
select the JRE you want to use and then click Finish.

Then right click click on the project name in the workspace. Select New -> Package

you can then enter the package name over here

Comment: thank you for the answer but I was asking about if I could have a new java application project wizard that also ask me about a package name.

Answer (score 1):

you can get description how to create new application in android in eclipse from this link:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Comment: I know that the wizard for new android application has it. I'm asking if I can have a normal java project wizard have it too.